# android - google places API with dijkstra algorithm

Tags: android, google-places-api, dijkstra

O'm working on an app for bus transit and route. I'm currently using `dijkstra algorithm` to find the shortest way from `bus stop A` to `bus stop B`, but it's still limited between bus stops. Is it possible to use `google places API`? for example, I put `coffee shop x` near `bus stop A` as `starting point` and `shopping mall y` near `bus stop B` as `destination` then the app calculates the shortest route from `bus stop A` to `bus stop B`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Comment: use google place distance API . it give you always short path . 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Comment: @HarshilKotecha do you mean that there's no need to make an own implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm?. I'm currently working on a very similar project but I haven't used google api's too much.

Comment: @Sandoval0992 yes in Google place api no need to use Dijkstra's alogrithm . Just give destination and current location lat long.  It's give all possible path in Json format array dictionary.In index [0] you can get sorted path

Comment: Is there anyway to use the google api distance matrix api and implement it on Dijkstra's Algorithm ?

Comment: I am working on the same kind project, may you please give me an idea how you worked on it.It would be really helpful.Thanks in advance